# Does gce copy-file command overwrite files if restarted following an error

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, file-copying

While transferring a large number of files out of a **GCE** instance using [copy-file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files) I encountered problems which caused the copy to fail.
Is the command able to recover/ resume where it left off or do I need to delete the partial transfer and start again to ensure an accurate copy is available at my destination location?

Example command run from destination folder

```
gcloud compute copy-files example-instance:/REMOTE-DIR/*  /subfolder/ --zone us-central1-a
```

Comment: Running the command to start the transfer again doesn't give any indication its overwriting existing files, creating a duplicate file as per the destination OS naming structure or that its starting off where it left off

Comment: Pretty sure, `copy-file` command works the same way a `cp` command would work on your machine, essentially overwriting completely.

Comment: Doesn't appear so judging by the time taken for the command executed the 2nd time to complete its operation

Comment: Could you please check modified time of the file? I have tested it on my side and it always updates the whole file. Try with smaller files.

Comment: Afraid I can't, i had to delete the gce cloud files